# Dismiss and show Dialog when change orientation in AsyncTask in ViewPager

Tags: android, dialog, android-viewpager, progressdialog

I have *ViewPager* with three pages. In one of them I show a *ProgressDialog* in an *AsyncTask*.

**Problem** is that when change orientation, *Dialog* is dismissed and doesn't appear.

Here is my code:

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity 
    android:name=".LecturaFragment"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  >
</activity>
```

*SherlockFragmentActivity*

```
lecturaFragment.new LoadingLecturaTask(this).execute(lecturas);

//In LecturaFragment (SherlockFragment)
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    dialog = null;
}

public class LoadingLecturaTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private Activity activity;
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private int lecturas;
    private String result = "";
    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    public LoadingLecturaTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }        

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading_envio));
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        lecturas = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        while (running) {
            try{
                ...                 
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I said, in change orientation, *ProgressDialog* disappears, but *AsyncTask* is still running. So what I want is, when change orientation and *Dialog* is dismissed, show it again until *AsyncTask* ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because whenever screen orientation changes activity is reload. You can solve this issue by single line in manifest.xml file

**Above Android 3.0**

```
<activity
            android:name="yourActivityWhichContainsViewPager"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            />
```

**Below Android 3.0**

```
<activity
            android:name="yourActivityWhichContainsViewPager"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            />
```

Comment: Wow! I've found the problem...I had it in `LecturaFragment`but not in `Activity`that contains `ViewPager`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to me your you `dismiss()` your dialog `in onPause()` so there may be a case that your activity is getting restarted but not your `AsyncTask`.

If possible please paste your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest...

```
<activity android:name="Your Activity Name"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: I forgot about that...I actually have it in my AndroidManifest (added right now in my question)